# How to click Button Class WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi, button, click, twebbrowser, submit-button

How to click in this button in TWebBrowser on Delphi

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="login()">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: Rather than simulating UI interaction post directly a login request. The `Navigate` method allows you to do that.

Comment: @TLama Yes, this is a solution. If the button submits a POST form, , all post data should be handled properly, otherwise server will not accept the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I do not have a Delphi compiler right now. The code is written using brain compiler. But it should work in general.*

### Use OleObject

You can use `oleobject` interface to access the DOM.

```
var
  Buttons: OleVariant;
  Button: OleVariant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Buttons := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for I := 0 to Buttons.Length - 1 do
  begin
    Button := Buttons.item(I);
    if Button.innerText = 'Sign in' then
    begin
      Button.click();
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

### Run External Script

Another approach is to call `execScript` interface. The benefit is that you can load a chunk of javascript code from external source, instead of compiling the whole project.

```
uses
  MSHTML_TLB, SHDocVw;

procedure ExecuteScript;
var
  Script: string;
  DocPtr: IHTMLDocument2;
  WinPtr: IHTMLWindow3;
begin
  Script := 'your_javascript_code'; // Alternatively read from file

  if Supports(WebBrowser1.Document, IHTMLDocument2, DocPtr) and
     Supports(DocPtr.parentWindow, IHTMLWindow3, WinPtr) then
    WinPtr.execScript(Script, 'javascript');
end;
```