# Delphi XE2 HTML PAGE how can i input value and press a button

Tags: html, delphi, input

I have a page loaded in TWebBrowser. I have two input field, first with name 'code' and the second with name 'text'. I have a button with caption VISUALISATION. I want to insert value in first and second input field and press button VISUALISATION. Please help. The HTML code is copy paste from Web source page.

```
<form name="codfiscalForm" method="POST" action="/infocodfiscal.html">
   <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="domenii">                           
      <p> &nbsp;</p>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text3">
     <tr>
       <td width="46%">Introduceti codul unic de identificare (numeric):</td>
       <td width="16%">
          <input name="cod" class="form2" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td> Cod de validare * </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>                                 
      <td> <img src="/artist.jpg"  border="0"></td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="text"  size="20" maxlength="10" ></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> </td>
       <td> &nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input name="B1" type="submit" class="form1" value="VISUALISATION" color="#0066ff" ></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Better sniff what is posted to that site and directly `Navigate` your browser there. The `Navigate` method has parameters for doing POST requests.

Comment: [Pressing Buttons on a web page via Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066692/pressing-buttons-on-a-web-page-via-delphi)  and [How to click Button Class WebBrowser Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399284/how-to-click-button-class-webbrowser-delphi)

Comment: @bummi, oh, I've said it even there :)

Comment: @TLama would need a cleanup maaaaany duplicates

Comment: I would use a code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/27U7WmQu) instead of simulating interaction (surely somehow better wrapped). It posts the same data as that [`VIZUALIZARE`](http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html) button does.

Comment: Or simply navigate to `http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=1234`, where 1234 is the fiscal code. But more precise to simulate that button click is sending those POST data (cannot find docs for that `cod` URL parameter).