# Automating a .php command in Delphi via oleobject

Tags: php, html, delphi, internet-explorer, automation

I'm relatively new to Delphi, so if the title doesn't match the contents of the question, my apologies. I'm looking to automate a process on a site that submits a form. I believe I've isolated the code from the site which handles this (values edited for account security) which is:

```
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
      <p class="center">
        <input type="hidden" name="StringOne" value="StringOneB" />
        <input type="hidden" name="StringTwo" value="StringTwoB" />
        <input type="hidden" name="StringThree" value="StringThreeB" />
        <input type="image" src="img/imageone.jpg" />
      </p>
    </form>
```

It is the only form on the page. The form is usually submitted via clicking imageone.jpg. The values of the three inputs are generated dynamically. How would I automate submission of this form? I planned to use the internet explorer OleObject. My code currently looks like

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      IE: variant;
    begin
      IE:= CreateOleObject('internetExplorer.Application');
      IE.visible := true;
      IE.navigate('http://thesite.com');
```

I have attempted to use the following (each line is a separate attempt):

```
      IE.Document.GetElementByID('StringOne').setAttribute('value', 'StringOneA', 0);
      //above won't work because input has no ID
      IE.Document.GetElementByName('StringOne').setAttribute('value', 'StringOneA', 0);
      //does not appear to be understood
      IE.OleObject.Document.forms[0].submit();
      IE.OleObject.Document.forms[1].submit();
      //does not appear to recognise the form
```

I've tried countless other lines of code, but none have been fruitful. Can this be done and if so, how? If any code could be explained, it would be helpful, as I am not well versed in OleObject automation. I can ham-handedly get the values from the HTML source, **the main focus of the question is simply submitting the form assuming I have the values**. Anything else is a bonus. If anything needs to be clarified, just say.

Comment: I'd like [`to say this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021441/delphi-xe2-html-page-how-can-i-input-value-and-press-a-button#comment42567323_27021441).

Comment: So am I correct in believing that the site will navigate to a page of the form: http://thesite.com/action.php/?stringone=stringoneb

Comment: Could be. It depends on how the site is implemented. From the client point of view on the code you posted we can only say that you should make a POST request with those values. But unless you tell us the site, we cannot be more specific. Or you can sniff the request that is performed and share it with us if you fear from telling us the site. The rest is quite trivial (you could even submit that form without IE, non-visually).

Comment: The HTML of the form does not have a submit button, so it needs JavaScript to work - please check the HTML source

Comment: @mjn: `<input type="image">` serves as a submit button, and will add `x` and `y` values with the coordinates of the click.

Comment: Why do you need IE for? use e.g. `TIdHTTP.Post` and grab the response. it's unclear what you are trying to "automate" here.